# load and insert an ASP.NET partial view using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a partial view of a row for the table. Each row in the table describes an element. An element can have child elements, but if it is a child element it cannot have it's own children. In the table, there is a row for each parent element, and a list of all of it's child elements. I am working on having a link next to the child elements that they can click, and it will no longer be a child. So it needs to be removed from the list, and a row added to the table under the parent element you just took it out of. I have the following javascript funciton that correctly updates the element in the database to no longer have a parent and removes it from the list.

```
    function removeElementFromParent(id, parentid) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this element from the group?")) {
            $.post('@Url.Content("~/Pack/RemoveElementFromParent")', { "elementid": id });
            $('#' + id).remove();
        }
    }
```

to create the row and insert it, I tried to do:

```
$('@Url.Action("~/Pack/ElementRow", new { elementid = id })').insertAfter('#' + parentid);
```

but that won't work since you cannot use the javascript variable id within @Url.Action(...). I have used the `$('#id').load(@Url.Action(...));` to load data as it is requested. I tried to do something similar, but since we don't have a defined place to load it, that wasn't going to work in this case. Also, you still wouldn't be able to use javascript variables.

if there is a better way to do this, some help would be greatly appreciated

---

**EDIT**

Here is my solution:

```
$('<tr id="' + id + '"></tr>').insertAfter('#' + parentid);
$('#' + id).load('@Url.Action("ElementRow")' + '?elementid=' + id);
```

Comment: You can try to write the actual url, not using the helpers. If it's a `post` request, u can write the parameters in the { data : id } parameters, if it's `get` u can write something like: { url: '/<Controller>/<Method>/' + id}. And there are some methods to return a partial view as a string to be parsed as Json. I think you can find your answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the javascript variable with Url.Action than you should to write something like this

```
$('@Url.Action("~/Pack/ElementRow")' + "?elementid=" + id).insertAfter('#' + parentid);
```

Hope this will fix you problem.